# Web3ValidatorError: Expected array, received string (validator response not matching ABI param definition)

Tags: javascript, typescript, parameters, web3js, nft

In the web3 space, there is a site that will build custom NFT contracts, per user needs. The expectation is that you are going to use their web-portal to interact with the contract they have provided for you.

I've built a separate web-app trying to integrate with their custom contract and *should be able to* still make function calls defined in this contract, but am having issues identifying the structure of parameters needed.

The abi for this particular function call:

```
   {
      "inputs": [
         {"internalType": "address", "name": "creatorContractAddress", "type": "address"},
         {"internalType": "uint256", "name": "instanceId", "type": "uint256"},
         {"internalType": "uint16", "name": "mintCount", "type": "uint16"},
         {"internalType": "uint32[]", "name": "mintIndices", "type": "uint32[]"},
         {"internalType": "bytes32[][]", "name": "merkleProofs", "type": "bytes32[][]"},
         {"internalType": "address", "name": "mintFor", "type": "address"}
      ],
      "name": "mintBatch",
      "outputs": [],
      "stateMutability": "payable",
      "type": "function"
   },
```

There is a very similar 'Mint' function as well, that one I"m able to call without issue, (params as shown below)

```
      "inputs": [
         {"internalType": "address", "name": "creatorContractAddress", "type": "address"},
         {"internalType": "uint256", "name": "instanceId", "type": "uint256"},
         {"internalType": "uint32", "name": "mintIndex", "type": "uint32"},
         {"internalType": "bytes32[]", "name": "merkleProof", "type": "bytes32[]"},
         {"internalType": "address", "name": "mintFor", "type": "address"}
      ],
```

these are the params for the two different calls:

```
Mint: (CREATOR_CONTRACT_ADDRESS, CONTRACT_INSTANCE_ID, 0, [], walletAddress) <-- successful

MintBatch: (CREATOR_CONTRACT_ADDRESS, CONTRACT_INSTANCE_ID, qty, [], new Array(new Array()), walletAddress) <-- failure
```

when I try to make a call to the 'MintBatch' function, i get this error:

```
Web3ValidatorError: Web3 validator found 6 error[s]:
Expected array, received string
Expected array, received string
Expected array, received number
must NOT have fewer than 2 items
must NOT have fewer than 2 items
Expected array, received string
```

Reading the error, I assumed maybe I needed to convert each arg into an array

```
        // for (var i = 0; i < qty; i++) {
        //   contracts.push(CREATOR_CONTRACT_ADDRESS);
        //   instance.push(CONTRACT_INSTANCE_ID);
        //   qtys.push(qty);
        //   indice.push(new Array());
        //   merkle.push(new Array(new Array()));
        //   wallet.push(walletAddress);
        // }
        // fCall = contract.methods.mintBatch(contracts, instance, qtys, indice, merkle, wallet);
```

, that didn't work,

I tried just passing the whole set as multiple array items,

```
        // args.push(new Array(CREATOR_CONTRACT_ADDRESS, CONTRACT_INSTANCE_ID, qty, [], new Array(new Array()), walletAddress))
```

that didn't work...

Most of these params are the same types as the original Mint call, so it's not clear why the error suggests that it 'Expected Array....'

I *think* its just this type that's problematic, I don't know how to build this in .ts
bytes32[][]

one final thing:, this is what the params for a successful call looks like, per contract history:

```
| param | name      | type        | value    |
| ----- | --------- | ----------- | -----    |
| 0 | conAdd        | address     | 0x98DadBafC2E65074398DF235255a9316aCc4Dd99   |
| 1 | instanceId    | uint256     | 72982768 |
| 2 | mintCount     | uint16      | 2        |
| 3 | mintIndices   | uint32[]    |          |
| 4 | merkleProofs  | bytes32[][] |          |
| 5 | mintFor       | address     | 0x4BD228771f09DB1894e3C97100c807aD37d80780 |
```

Been stuck on this for a bit, could really use a second set of eyes. thank you.